# Iterator references wrong string

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to map a string to a function like so in Node.js.

```
function foo(data) {
    //foo body
}

function bar(data) {
    //bar body
}

var FUNCTION_MAP = {
    "foo": foo,
    "bar": bar
}


for (var event in FUNCTION_MAP) {
    socket.on(event, function(data) {
        FUNCTION_MAP[event](data);
    });
}
```

Some hand-testing shows that `event` will always be `"bar"`, so the bar function is always called regardless of what event is invoked, i.e. whether the client calls `socket.emit("foo", {})` or `socket.emit("bar", {})`, the `bar` function is always called on the server side. Even creating a new string object doesn't work.

```
for (var event in FUNCTION_MAP) {
    socket.on(event, function(data) {
        FUNCTION_MAP[new String(event)](data);
    });
}
```

Why does `event` retain the value `"bar"` after the loop terminates? What can I do to create a string object that has its own value and doesn't reference the `event` variable?

Comment: just curious in regards to your for loop replace the var with let and see what happens.

Comment: I get the same result whether I use `var` or `let`.

Comment: All good, I was just curious, the duplicate answer is the solution then.